# Why is the border of my textblock not a border?

Tags: wpf, xaml, border, textblock

I have just created this `TextBlock` in my XAML file:

```
<TextBlock Text="blabla"> <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" /> </TextBlock>
```

I was expecting the word "blabla" with a black border (**around** it), but instead I get this:

[image]

Please mind the very tiny black square in the left bottom edge :-)

Can anybody tell me how to put a border around my `TextBlock`?

Comment: Have you tried to put the `TextBlock` into the `Border` ?

Comment: `...border around my TextBlock?` - so close :) - what you did was literally the other way around you have a textblock around a border.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `TextBlock` needs to be wrapped by the `Border`. Example:

```
<Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
    <TextBlock Text="blabla"></TextBlock>
</Border>
```